# Update two Google documents at the same time

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have a copy of a Google sheet (single sheet) that I want populated everytime someone edits the original. Is this possible?

Comment: Since I didn't know it's possible, I didn't know what to try. Could you please point me in the right direction? Maybe I could work out something since I now know it's possible.

Comment: It depends on what you want updated. People usually update a single sheet or a specific range. Which one is your case? Your question is quite vague and general.

Comment: In this case, please have a look at this [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138200/117311). I believe it is exactly what you are after.

Comment: So I need `importrange` ? Let me try that. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Let's clean up all these chat as well and keep the essential ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `importrange`

Example: `importrange("url", "range")`

Thanks to @marikamitsos for helping out.